# Oracle/SQL Couting multiple colums grouped by a common column

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

I'm back with yet another Oracle query.  What I want to do is do counting on multiple columns grouped by a common field. I have half of this done so far.  So given the following table

```
THING ACTION
--------------
T1  _A_
T1  _A_
T1  _B_
T2  _A_
T2  _B_
```

I have this query

```
select    THING,
    count(ACTION) as "A"
 from  <table>
 where  ACTION = '_A_'
 group by THING
```

Which results in

```
THING A
----------
T1    2
T2    1
```

What I would like to see though is this

```
THING A B
--------------
T1    2   1
T2    1   1
```

But I'm not certain how to do that. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select thing,
       count(case action when '_A_' then 1 end) as a,
       count(case action when '_B_' then 1 end) as b
from <table>
group by thing
```

or `sum(case action when '_A_' then 1 else 0 end)` if you prefer